# Javascript eventListeners not firing

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to get all buttons to do the same on click like the first button does.
Basically, it's just calling a function on click.

That function changes the innerHtml of the target div, adds a Css animation class, then removes the Css animation on mouseout.

This works exactly how i want it to on the first button, but not one the second and last.

```
function declaration() {
    document.getElementById("me").innerHTML = "I am a function declaration and i                
    hoist to the top of the code, you
    can call me before i get
    declared.I look like this: < br > function declaration() {}
    ";
    document.getElementById("me")
        .classList.add("slideIt");
    document.getElementById("fnDeclaration")
        .addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            document.getElementById("me")
                .classList.remove("slideIt");
        });
}
document.getElementById("fnDeclaration").addEventListener("click", function() {
    declaration();
});
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/xwJmwN

Why is this (not) happening?

Comment: @Azzi
It's in the post, a link to codepen, it was not displayed properly before:-)

Answer (score 0):

Your content div (`#me`) is set-up last in the HTML (hence in DOM), so it sits on top of your buttons when sliding down.

Therefore you actually `mouseout` from your button as soon as the sliding down animation starts, which as per your code removes the `slideIt` class, hence stops the animation.

A quick fix could simply be to push your content div down below (z-index-wise) your buttons: `#me {z-index: -10;}`

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNvqYx

Comment: This is very interesting I would have never thought about this, however, it still does not work. Only the first button reacts as its supposed to.

Comment: Hm, that is most odd, for me, in your link, the first button adds the animation and removes the Css animation class on mouseout, the second and the last button only change the innerHTML on click, but no animation.

Comment: Just in case, I updated the codepen by specifying a `z-index` on buttons to make sure they are on top of `#me`… Give it a try now. What browser / version are you using?

Comment: I have just tried, still the same. 
I am using Chrome 46.0.2490.80 , am updating it now, and will try FF as well

Comment: It works in FF, but not in Chrome(updated).
This is mysterious:-)

Comment: Fine for me on Chrome and FF. Sorry I cannot help you further since I am unable to reproduce the issue at this point. Are you leaving your mouse on the button the whole time?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help, the tip you gave me about the DOM alone makes the whole effort worth it.
No, I go over the buttons, the mouseout.
Now, one thing comes to mind, I do not use a mouse, but the laptop touch-surfac, could this possibly be the reason?

Comment: Could be, if for some reason the pointer moves while / just after clicking. Try to replace your `mouseout` by a timeout for example, and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried it using a mouse, no cigar:-)
Explain the timeout test please, I did not get it.

Comment: ghybs might mean for you to set a timer, so that you don't have to wait for a mouseout-event (which could be not working as expected at the moment).